# Center Grid Of Images Responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html, responsive-design, center

I'm having a huge issue with centring my div here: http://www.divisionforty.com/wall/artists/ I can not for the life of me get the boxes to centre in the screen. I've tried margin: 0 auto; but for some reason I can not get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated,

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="work">
        <div class="span12">
            <figure >
                <a href="http://www.divisionforty.com/wall/artists/cali-balles/">
                    <img width="200" height="200" src="http://www.divisionforty.com/wall/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Cali-Balles-05b-250x250.jpg" class="attachment-artists wp-post-image" alt="Cali Balles, Branch Series [detail] Blown Glass 2010" />
                    <dd>
                        Balles, Cali                            
                    </dd>
                </a> 
            </figure>
```

CSS

```
/*Artists*/

.work {


}

.work figure {
  float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;

  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width:250px;
  height: 250px;
  line-height: 200px;
  -webkit-filter: sepia(0.4);
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 !important;


  transition: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: 0.6s;
  -o-transition: 0.6s;
  -ms-transition: 0.6s;
}
```

Comment: please provide the relevant code here

Comment: I don't know what you'd consider relevant code

Comment: code that represents the problem, for instance the code that makes up your menu would not be relevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `margin:0 auto;` style on the `span12` div, but since bootstrap sets a `float:left` to their 
span* classes you need to reset it to not float

```
.work .span12 {
   float:initial;
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

`float:initial` resets the float back to its default value

This will center the div within the `work` div

Comment: Its still a little off centre. any ideas?

Comment: yea seems there is a bit of extra white space on the right side within the span12 div at the moment cannot see what is generating the extra white space though.

Comment: So what would ya suggest?

Comment: using `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left` for your `figure` elements seems to get rid of the extra white space on the right side

Comment: Any ideas why it would not centre as it scales down?

Comment: unfortunately that has to do with the images being resized, the container span12 has a static width, so it doesn't shrink wrap (doesnt shrink when the images do), Your best bet would be to try using more of the bootstrap grid layouts for within the span12, http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html describes bootstraps grid system.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
.row {
  width: 1200px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

*Edit: nevermind, the other answer is better. This would break the responsive.*